# swiftUI The compiler is unable to type-check this... when trying to use data from server API

Tags: swift, swiftui

I make network request and want to parse and display result, but it does not compile and gives

```
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expression
```

I have this view:

```
struct SummaryView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var state: AppState
@State var responsePriceFromServer: OrderStatusResp? = nil
@State var loading: Bool = true

var body: some View {
    self.state.makeAPICall( success: nil, successData: { data in
        if let d = try! JSONDecoder().decode(OrderStatusResp?.self, from: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                responsePriceFromServer = d
                loading = false
            }
            return
        }
    }, failure: { err in
        print("Failed to load client order detail: " + err)
    }
    )
    return ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        if !loading {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    responsePriceFromServer?.order?.amount
                }
        }else {
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                Color(rgb: "FEFEFE")
            }

        }
    }

  }
}
```

and this response class:

```
struct OrderStatusResp: Hashable, Codable {
var order: OrderStatus?
var result: Bool?
var msg: String?
}

struct OrderStatus: Hashable, Codable {
var id: Int?
var status: Int?
var paid: Int?
var amount: Int?
var discountSum: Int?
var items: [OrderStatusItem]
}

struct OrderStatusItem: Hashable, Codable {
var price: Int
var discounted: Int
var total: Int
var name: String
var code: Int
var quantity: Int
}
```

However when I display it in this way it works ok:

```
                    Text("\(state.responsePriceFromServer?.order?.items ?? [] )")
```

what is the problem?

P.S
I searched other similar answer from stack and documentation but nothing helped

Comment: This `responsePriceFromServer?.order?.amount` needs to be unwrapped and then added to Text. You cannot display values in that way. If you want to display Text then it needs to be something like `Text("\(responsePriceFromServer?.order?.amount ?? 0)")`.

Comment: Seems very bad way to make API calls... If you call that on body property, the API would be called on each body render!

Answer (score 1):

General advice when compiler says its unable to compile something in reasonable time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67025833/11837341

#### Answer

In a `VStack`, you cant enter a plain string, because a plain string is not a `View`, and a `VStack` only accepts a `View`. Instead of `VStack { someString }` you must do `VStack { Text(someString) }` because `Text` is a `View` (e.g. conforms to the `View` protocol)

#### Notes

Dont do that to yourself! Don't call the api in the view body like that, that can make way too many api calls, more than you need. Instead perform your api call in a `.onAppear()`